# How do I monitor Apache AJP connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, network-monitoring

I need to monitor the number of existing connections made by Apache to the different instances of JBoss in my *NIX server. How do I do that? If that tool or method gives me more info that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for a way to see all the outbound AJP connections from the Apache side.  But if it helps, you *can* monitor this on the JBoss side instead.  For example, the "scoreboard" view at `http://yourjbossserver:8080/status?full=true` shows a complete list of all AJP connections, with total bytes sent and received plus a few other goodies.

If you want to do it via scripting, you could use `twiddle.sh` instead.  For example (on a JBoss server):

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/twiddle.sh get "jboss.web:name=ajp-0.0.0.0-8009,type=ThreadPool" currentThreadsBusy
```

This would output:

```
currentThreadsBusy=10
```

(or whatever)

Comment: Hey thanks man. What is a good reference in your opinion for the twiddle script?

Comment: The command-line help is pretty good (twiddle.sh --help).  You can find more on Google ;-).  One document that turned up is at http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/Command_Line_Access_to_JMX-Sample_twiddle_Command_Usage.html.

Answer (score 0):

supposing you are using mod_jk have a look at the status worker:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/status.html